# Store activation key in separated table using myisam

Tags: mysql, transactions, myisam, activation

I want to make a login system. I want a confirmation by sending an activation code (clickable link) by email. I considered storing the activation key in separate table from the user information, since these are only relevant for non-activated users. When a user registers a row containing user information would be inserted in the users table and the activation key in the activation table. Once the link is clicked, I remove the record from the activation table.
But since I have no way of using innodb on my hosting, this is not fault-proof since I can't use transactions. I have 2 options. 
Option A:
I keep the key in the activation table.
I store a boolean in the user table to check whether activation is necessary. If activation is needed and there is no record to be found in activation table, there can be a new attempt to add the record and resend an email to the user. 
* more checks (php, in case no record was found)
* joins in selects for checking
* more inserts/deletes/updates

Option B:
Or I can store the activation key in the user table, having to use more space, that is not always used. 
*Does unused storage always take up space using myisam?
*what is the recommended length for an activation key?
*Is the boolean still needed or can I set the activation key to NULL in order to check whether a user has been activated or not?

What is the best solution and why? Speed, space,....?

Answer (score 0):

The heart of your question seems to relate to the moment of activation. You seem to be concerned that you'll get a transactional race condition around activation, and you won't be able to prevent it because you must use MyISAM instead of InnoDB.

This doesn't seem to be a critical problem. No harm will be done if a new user attempts to activate multiple times with the same correct token, or if she attempts to activate with an incorrect token at the same time as a correct token.

What is a critical success factor? The performance of a normal authentication operation (login) for an active user.  If your query must join to a separate activation-token table for every users that logs in, that's not going to give you ideal performance. Neither is a query containing a clause like this:

```
  AND user.activation_token IS NOT NULL
```

You may want to use a Boolean column value (a short integer) to indicate "activation pending" in your user table. If that column comes up true during normal login, you can invoke the extra, infrequently used, logic for activation. If, for example, you need to be able to accelerate this operation:

```
  SELECT hashed_password, activation_pending
    FROM user
   WHERE username = ?
```

you can create a compound index on `(username, hashed_password, activation_pending)` and make that operation very efficient. Then when you successfully complete the pending activation (a relatively infrequent operation), you can do these two operations.

```
  UPDATE user 
     SET activation_pending = 0
   WHERE user = ?;

  DELETE
    FROM activation_token
   WHERE user = ?;
```

Once `activation_pending` is set to zero, that's enough for the race condition: your logic won't look at your activation_token table.

`varchar` columns don't take much space if they contain zero-length strings. `char` columns do.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This makes perfect sense!